# Joda-Time Formatting for Islamic Date

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to get the [Islamic date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar) in the dd MMMM yyyy but I am always getting dd MM yyyy.

Any advise? could it be that Hijri dates are not supported for formatting? It's not clear on the Joda-Time website.

```
 DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2014,2,25,0,0,0,0);
 DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance());
 String formatIslamic= "dd MMMM yyyy";
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(formatIslamic).withChronology( IslamicChronology.getInstance());
 String islamicDateString = formatter.print(dtIslamic);
```

Comment: Have a look here
[Joda Time bug or my mistake?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525932/joda-time-bug-or-my-mistake-java-joda-time-dates-as-strings-parsing

The second answer provides a workaround.

Comment: Try out solution described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1572131/1688570 it worked for me.

Comment: thank you @TouDick but i used another solution that doesn't use JODA.

Answer (score 3):

This is currently not implemented.  The BasicChronology class sets the monthOfYear field to use GJMonthOfYearDateTimeField which in turn gets it's data from java.text.DateFormatSymbols.  The IslamicChronology uses a sets the monthOfYear field to a BasicMonthOfYearDateTimeField which has the following implementation of getAsText:

```
public String getAsText(int fieldValue, Locale locale) {
    return Integer.toString(fieldValue);
}
```

What someone needs to do is to create a IslamicMonthOfYearDateTimeField that extends BasicMonthOfYearDateTimeField and overrides the method so that it returns the name of the month rather than the numeric value of the month.  This could either be done in the joda-time codebase, or completely outside.  To get this working outside of joda, just extend IslamicChronology and override assemble to pull in your new IslamicMonthOfYearDateTimeField.  I'd issue a pull request to joda-time myself, but I doubt they'd accept a non-localized solution.

Comment: thank you for your response but I used another implementation without using JODA.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.chrono.HijrahDate.from(
    LocalDate.of( 2014 , 2 , 25 ) 
)
.get( ChronoField.YEAR )
```

> 1435

## java.time

The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance mode, advising migration to the *java.time* classes.

The *java.time* classes offer a [`HijrahChronology`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahChronology.html) and [`HijrahDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahDate.html) in the [`java.time.chrono`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/package-summary.html) package.

For Java 6 & 7, and for earlier Android, the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project also offers a [`HijrahChronology`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/chrono/HijrahChronology.html) and `HijrahDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2014 , 2 , 25 ) ;
HijrahDate hd = HijrahDate.from( ld  );
String output = hd.toString() ;
```

> output: Hijrah-umalqura AH 1435-04-25

As for other formats, the `format` method with `DateTimeFormatter` seem to revert to ISO chronology.

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag( "en-US-u-ca-islamic-umalqura" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale );
String output2 = hd.format( f );
```

> output2: Tuesday, February 25, 2014

While I do not have time at the moment to do so, I suggest looking at the source code of the [`HijrahDate::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/HijrahDate.html#toString()) method.

You can roll-your-own formatting by using the example code as seen in the [*java.time.chrono*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/chrono/package-summary.html) package documentation.

```
int day = hd.get( ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH );
int dow = hd.get( ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK );
int month = hd.get( ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR );
int year = hd.get( ChronoField.YEAR );
System.out.printf( "%s %s %d-%s-%d%n" , hd.getChronology().getId() , dow , day , month , year );
```

> Hijrah-umalqura 2 25-4-1435

---

See also:

[*Convert Jalali calendar to Georgian in java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49637134/642706)

[*Get a gregorian date from Hijri date strings*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792256/get-a-gregorian-date-from-hijri-date-strings)

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for this :) I had my app crash last year because of a library, re-built the entire app and didn't know it's the library cuz there was another error. Lost all my hope but then found your answers and ThreeTenABP, wonderful work mate!