# Formatting Joda time with Ethiopic Chronology not displaying the name of the month

Tags: datetime, grails, groovy, jodatime

I'm using Joda time to convert gregorian date and time to Ethiopic chronology and I'm trying to format it with "MMMM dd, yyyy" format. I expect the Date to be displayed as "Meskerem 01, 2007" instead I get "1 01, 2007". Is this a bug in Joda time or am I doing something wrong?

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy")
Date time myDate = new DateTime(2014,9,11,0,0,0,0).withChronology(EthiopicChronology.getInstance()).toString(dtf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, JodaTime has never been good in internationalization, sorry. But I will present a workaround.

```
DateTimePrinter printer =
        new DateTimePrinter() {

    @Override
    public int estimatePrintedLength() {
        return 8; // type the maximum chars you need for printing ethiopic months
    }

    @Override
    public void printTo(StringBuffer buf, ReadablePartial partial, Locale locale) {
        int index = LocalDate.now().indexOf(DateTimeFieldType.monthOfYear());
        int month = partial.getValue(index);
        print(buf, month);
    }

    @Override
    public void printTo(Writer out, ReadablePartial partial, Locale locale)
        throws IOException
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        printTo(sb, partial, locale);
        out.write(sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void printTo(
        StringBuffer buf,
        long         instant,
        Chronology   chrono,
        int          displayOffset,
        DateTimeZone displayZone,
        Locale       locale
    ) {
        LocalDate date = new LocalDate(instant, EthiopicChronology.getInstance());
        print(buf, date.getMonthOfYear());
    }

    @Override
    public void printTo(
        Writer       out,
        long         instant,
        Chronology   chrono,
        int          displayOffset,
        DateTimeZone displayZone,
        Locale       locale
    ) throws IOException
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        printTo(sb, instant, chrono, displayOffset, displayZone, locale);
        out.write(sb.toString());
    }

    private void print(StringBuffer buf, int month) {
        switch (month) {
            case 1 : // attention: ethiopic month index
                buf.append("Meskerem");
                break;
            // case 2: etc.
            default :
                buf.append(month);
        }
    }
};

DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(printer).appendPattern(" dd, yyyy").toFormatter();
Chronology chronology = EthiopicChronology.getInstance();
DateTime ethiopic = new DateTime(2014, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0).withChronology(chronology);
String myDate = ethiopic.toString(dtf);
System.out.println(ethiopic); // 2007-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00 (ethiopic month number and year and day-of-month!!!)
System.out.println(myDate); // Meskerem 01, 2007
```

**Just to note:** This code (as suggested by @Opal?) does not work for me:

```
Chronology chronology = EthiopicChronology.getInstance();
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy").withChronology(chronology);
String myDate = new DateTime(2014, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0).toString(dtf2);
System.out.println(myDate); // 1 01, 2007
```

The reason is the sad fact that Joda-Time does not manage its own text resources for non-gregorian chronologies, compare also this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525932/joda-time-bug-or-my-mistake-java-joda-time-dates-as-strings-parsing). You can also use a specialized field implementation as suggested in that post. Here I have presented a solution using `DateTimePrinter` on which you have to add the missing month names you need.

Comment: Nice, got +1 from me! :)

Comment: @Opal Thank you very much, but if the solution is nice? I am not sure, It has taken me some time to work out the code which is still incomplete and does not claim to be perfect. It is also such an effort that I believe a simple string processing instead of using a dedicated printer is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example below:

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.7') 
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.chrono.EthiopicChronology

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy")
println new DateTime(2014,9,11,0,0,0,0).toString(dtf)
```

It prints the date correctly - full month name. Now have a look at the [docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withChronology-org.joda.time.Chronology-). It states that `Chronology` object returns a **new** formatter. Probably this is not a bug but the just returned formatter is used instead of the one defined.

**UPDATE**

It might be a bug, it doesn't work with `BuddhistChronology` as well:

```
@Grab(group='joda-time', module='joda-time', version='2.7') 
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.chrono.*

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy")
println new DateTime(2014,9,11,0,0,0,0).withChronology(BuddhistChronology.getInstance()).toString(dtf)
```

Comment: Yeah it prints the date correctly because you are not using the Ethiopic chronology in this example. I tried my code with a different format, "dd/MM/yyyy". The output is printed properly as "01/01/2007"

Comment: I've updated my answer, as I said it might be a bug.